# How can I calculate the accuracy of words?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, textblob

I am using a textbob for calculate the accuracy  of the words.

```
text = 'thank you calling on product support talking to caafic k y please helping with your a digit employ number   ing'
orig_words = text.split()
fixed_words = TextBlob(text).correct().split()
words=(len([(x,y) for x,y in zip(orig_words, fixed_words) if x != y])) # => 3
total_word_len=len(orig_words)
correct_words=total_word_len-words
accuraccy=correct_words/total_word_len
```

but the problem is it is considering the  'caafic' ,'k', 'y' ,'ing' as the correct word. Ideally these should not be considered as correct words.

Comment: As a hint, do print the `fixed_words` to see what `TextBlob(text).correct()` is actually doing. Check the [documentation](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/api_reference.html#textblob.blob.TextBlob.correct) as well.

Comment: more detailed hint, try this `list(zip(orig_words, fixed_words))`. that should tell you the answer to why you get an accuracy of 1.0.

Comment: i got below when i print list(zip(orig_words, fixed_words))
[('thank', 'thank'),
 ('you', 'you'),
 ('calling', 'calling'),
 ('on', 'on'),
 ('product', 'product'),
 ('support', 'support'),
 ('talking', 'talking'),
 ('to', 'to'),
 ('caafic', 'caafic'),
 ('k', 'k'),
 ('y', 'y'),
 ('please', 'please'),
 ('helping', 'helping'),
 ('with', 'with'),
 ('your', 'your'),
 ('a', 'a'),
 ('digit', 'digit'),
 ('employ', 'employ'),
 ('number', 'number'),
 ('ing', 'ing')] if you see i dont want ing, k ,p as the corrected words. it should be considered as the incorrect word

Comment: correct. as you can see. this will obviously result in an accuracy of 1 because both the original and fixed sentences are the same, word by word. This is because (as per documentation) the `.correct()` method only `Attempts to correct the spelling of a blob`.  Meaning, it tries to correct `product->product` and when it fails to correct `ing` it just returns it as it is.

Comment: but i dont want 'k','y','ing' as correct words. do you any idea what's alternate method.